# Unable to mount files in Docker

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, mount

## Error description

I'm unable to mount files in Vagrant or Docker, so it seems like it's an issue caused by some kind of a permission error.
My OS is `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)`, I'm not running any access control modules like `SELinux` as far as I'm aware.

The Vagrant-related discussion of the error is found in another question:
[Unable to mount files in Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511013/unable-to-mount-files-in-vagrant)

## Troubleshooting Docker

I'm unable to mount files into a Docker container with docker-compose, I'm trying to build: https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/saltstack-docker

I set my volumes in the `docker-compose` file to:

```
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/assets/master/etc/supervisor:/etc/supervisor
  - ${PWD}/assets/master/etc/salt:/etc/salt
  - ${PWD}/assets/master/var/cache/salt:/var/cache/salt
  - ${PWD}/assets/master/var/log/salt:/var/log/salt
  - ${PWD}/assets/master/srv:/srv
```

Yet I'm getting this output when running `docker-compose up`:

```
Creating network "saltstack_default" with the default driver
Creating salt_image
Creating salt
Creating minion
Attaching to salt, minion, salt_image
salt      | Error: could not find config file /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
salt      | For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
salt exited with code 2
salt_image exited with code 0
minion    | [ERROR   ] DNS lookup of 'salt' failed.
minion    | [ERROR   ] Master hostname: 'salt' not found. Retrying in 30 seconds
```

`docker inspect`ing the container shows correct configuration:

```
   "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/somedir/saltstack/assets/master/etc/salt",
            "Destination": "/etc/salt",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/somedir/saltstack/assets/master/var/cache/salt",
            "Destination": "/var/cache/salt",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/somedir/saltstack/assets/master/etc/supervisor",
            "Destination": "/etc/supervisor",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/somedir/saltstack/assets/master/var/log/salt",
            "Destination": "/var/log/salt",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/somedir/saltstack/assets/master/srv",
            "Destination": "/srv",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
```

But entering the container (with another entrypoint command), shows that the files that are supposed to be mounted are missing:

```
[root@salt /]# ll /etc/supervisor
total 0
[root@salt /]# ll /etc/salt
total 0
[root@salt /]# ll /var/cache/salt
total 0
[root@salt /]# ll /var/log/salt
total 0
[root@salt /]# ll /srv
total 0
```

## Conclusion

It seems something is very messed up on my local machine when it comes to copying over files, possibly has to do with how my user is configured and what access it has to mounting files into VMs and containers.
If anyone can shed some light on this I'd appreciate it.

## Updates

### Update 1

I'm suspecting this is an issue with old stuff in `/var/lib/docker` which I'm about to remove, but before that here's another error I'm getting, maybe some kind of permission error:

```
> cat docker-compose.yml 
# based on https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/nginx/#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
     - ./testfile.txt:/etc/nginx/
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    environment:
     - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
     - NGINX_PORT=80
    command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

> docker-compose up
Creating network "docker_compose-mounting_issue_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_compose-mounting_issue_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for docker_compose-mounting_issue_web_1  Cannot start service web: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \\"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\\\\"/home/.../troubleshoot/docker_compose-mounting_issue/testfile.txt\\\\\\" to rootfs \\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/580b79241399e838c67b74021ecf2597aade5f1711811f4ab5c9c7bbcd188449\\\\\\" at \\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/580b79241399e838c67b74021ecf2597aade5f1711811f4ab5c9c7bbcd188449/etc/nginx\\\\\\" caused \\\\\\"not a directory\\\\\\"\\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type'

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \\"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\\\\"/home/.../troubleshoot/docker_compose-mounting_issue/testfile.txt\\\\\\" to rootfs \\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/580b79241399e838c67b74021ecf2597aade5f1711811f4ab5c9c7bbcd188449\\\\\\" at \\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/580b79241399e838c67b74021ecf2597aade5f1711811f4ab5c9c7bbcd188449/etc/nginx\\\\\\" caused \\\\\\"not a directory\\\\\\"\\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

### Update 2

So I removed everything in `/var/lib/docker/` and it now works as it should, mounting my files. It was probably broken somewhere. Another suggestion I came across was giving permissions to the directory, `chmod 777` seemed to help some users but I don't think this is that safe..

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested that this might be caused by AUFS storage driver, I will further investigate this.

Comment: Is the PWD inside `/vagrant` or a `nfs` shared volume?

Comment: Could it be AppArmor? Do you happen to have any `apparmor="DENIED"` lines in the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `docker info`, `docker version`, and maybe the complete output of `docker inspect <container>`?

Comment: TarunLalwani Vagrant has nothing to do with this Docker build; 
GaborLengyel I don't see any message about apparmor;
gesellix here you go: https://pastebin.com/Uk9VeFWQ

Answer (score 1):

what folder permission that the user has(the one you are logged into run the docker-compose command), if that is is root user or the user has access to the folders and please change the ${PWD} to the relative/absolute path of the folder(one which you want to mount to container).
docker-compose cant understand the ${PWD} env variable.

Ex: if you want to mount

> ${PWD}/assets/master/etc/supervisor:/etc/supervisor

it should be

> ./assets/master/etc/supervisor:/etc/supervisor

Comment: Changed but still the same issue, probably not related to the path.

Comment: @PetrusK.Can you add your folder structure and and from where you are running docker command .!